# Can I do a dry run of `do-release-upgrade`?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I previously tried to `do-release-upgrade` a VM running Ubuntu 14.04 server.  The upgrade process kept halting to ask me what to do about config files that were not as expected, which I didn't know how to answer, because why would I.  While spending several hours researching each file in turn to try to figure what to do with each one, the SSH connection (or something) dropped, and the upgrade halted as botched.  I had to restore the VM from backup.

I'd like to try again.  Is there any way to "dry run" `do-release-upgrade` to find out in advance what questions it's going to ask me so I can be prepared this time?  There's nothing in the `man` page about a dry run, and web searches turn up nothing.

Comment: I'm a little confused about why you are the person doing the upgrade, but you don't know anything about the non-default config files.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I've been there.  Consider...  People come and go.  Some messes are inherited with management's view "just keep it running".

Comment: @MarcoShaw Ug.  It's always nice to leave a little trail of breadcrumbs

Comment: @CharlesGreen How does one be part of such a wonderful parallel universe?

Comment: Just keep swimming!

Comment: I just had a thought...  What kind of VM/system is this?  Get your virtual administrator to create a snap shot of your system and do your "dry run" then back it out?  I think there's just way too much going on to assume you can get everything you need beforehand.

Comment: @MarcoShaw Probably a really, really good idea:  The behavior of programs (beyond just the OS) may have changed, and there might be a lot of fixin' to do.

Comment: @MarcoShaw That's what I ended up doing.  It can take a day or so for the VM admin to be able to get to a request like that, so I was hoping I could avoid hassling him.